# xamarin forms page not scrolled

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, android-virtual-device

I'm beginner in xamarin forms and I have been download [Todo project](http://%3C?xml%20version=%221.0%22%20encoding=%22UTF-8%22?%3E%20%3CContentPage%20xmlns=%22http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms%22%20xmlns:x=%22http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml%22%20x:Class=%22Todo.TodoItemPage%22%20x:Name=%22page%22%20Title=%22Todo%20Item%22%3E%20%09%3CStackLayout%20Margin=%2220%22%20VerticalOptions=%22StartAndExpand%22%3E%20%09%09%3CLabel%20Text=%22Name%22%20/%3E%20%09%09%3CEntry%20Text=%22%7BBinding%20Source=%7Bx:Reference%20page%7D,%20Path=TodoItem.Name%7D%22%20Placeholder=%22Enter%20task%20name%20here%22%20/%3E%20%09%09%3CActivityIndicator%20HorizontalOptions=%22Center%22%20IsRunning=%22%7BBinding%20Source=%7Bx:Reference%20page%7D,%20Path=IsProcessing%7D%22%20/%3E%20%09%09%3CStackLayout%20Orientation=%22Horizontal%22%20HorizontalOptions=%22Center%22%3E%20%09%09%09%3CButton%20Image=%22record.png%22%20Clicked=%22OnRecognizeSpeechButtonClicked%22%20/%3E%20%09%09%09%3CButton%20Image=%22spellcheck.png%22%20Clicked=%22OnSpellCheckButtonClicked%22%20/%3E%20%09%09%09%3CButton%20Image=%22translate.png%22%20Clicked=%22OnTranslateButtonClicked%22%20/%3E%20%09%09%3C/StackLayout%3E%20%09%09%3CLabel%20Text=%22Done%22%20/%3E%20%09%09%3CSwitch%20IsToggled=%22%7BBinding%20Source=%7Bx:Reference%20page%7D,%20Path=TodoItem.Done%7D%22%20/%3E%20%09%09%3CButton%20Text=%22Save%22%20Clicked=%22OnSaveClicked%22%20/%3E%20%09%09%3CButton%20Text=%22Delete%22%20Clicked=%22OnDeleteClicked%22%20/%3E%20%09%09%3CButton%20Text=%22Cancel%22%20Clicked=%22OnCancelClicked%22%20/%3E%20%09%3C/StackLayout%3E%20%3C/ContentPage%3E).
My main problem is that the view pages does't appear correctly and I don't know what's the problem exactly.
Here is my code :

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="Todo.TodoItemPage" x:Name="page" Title="Todo Item">
<StackLayout Margin="20" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
    <Label Text="Name" />
    <Entry Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference page}, Path=TodoItem.Name}" Placeholder="Enter task name here" />
    <ActivityIndicator HorizontalOptions="Center" IsRunning="{Binding Source={x:Reference page}, Path=IsProcessing}" />
    <Label Text="Done" />
    <Switch IsToggled="{Binding Source={x:Reference page}, Path=TodoItem.Done}" />
    <Button Text="Save" Clicked="OnSaveClicked" />
    <Button Text="Delete" Clicked="OnDeleteClicked" />
    <Button Text="Cancel" Clicked="OnCancelClicked" />
</StackLayout>
```

And here is screenshot from this page. As you can see `Delete` and `Cancel` button doesn't appear and I cant scroll in this page.

[image]

I think maybe my AVD have a problem. you can see below screenshot when AVD is loading.

[image] .

You can see AVD setting in below image too

[image]

If the problem only is in AVD  why I can't scroll in page. If I run this application in real device with small screen it seems like this?

What's the main problem and how I can resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add your Layout to a ScrollView so you can Scroll it.